# checkbox like radiobutton wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

i have investigated this problem but this is solved in design view and code-behind. but my problem is little difference: i try to do this as only code-behind because my checkboxes are dynamically created  according to database data.In other words, number of my checkboxes is not stable. i want to check only one checkbox in group of checkboxes. when i clicked one checkbox,i want that ischecked property of other checkboxes become false.this is same property in radiobuttons. i take my checkboxes from a stackpanel in xaml side:

```
<StackPanel Margin="4" Orientation="Vertical"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="companiesContainer">
            </StackPanel>
```

my xaml.cs:

```
using (var c = new RSPDbContext())
        {
            var q = (from v in c.Companies select v).ToList();

            foreach (var na in q)
            {
                CheckBox ch = new CheckBox();
                ch.Content = na.Name;
                ch.Tag = na;
                companiesContainer.Children.Add(ch);
            }
        }

foreach (object i in companiesContainer.Children)
            {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)i;

                chk.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, "DataItem.IsChecked");
            }
```

how can i provide this property in checkboxes in xaml.cs ? 
thanks in advance..

Comment: Any reason you want to make check boxes behave like radio buttons instead of using radio buttons?

Comment: i just wonder how to do this.i wanted to try this.

Comment: sorry..now i realized i have a choice that none of these checkboxes can be checked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an an event handler for the checked event.  When creating the checkbox, add this (same) event handler to each checkbox.

In the event handler, run through each checkbox you've added, and for every checkbox, uncheck it UNLESS it's the same checkbox as the sender.

That I think should do the trick (off the top of my head).

Here is some code I just knocked up that should help:

XAML part is just a stack panel called:  Name="checkboxcontainer"

Codebehind part:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CreateCheckboxes();
    }

    private void CreateCheckboxes()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
            c.Name = "Check" + i.ToString();
            c.Checked += c_Checked; //This is adding the event handler to the checkbox
            checkboxcontainer.Children.Add(c);
        }
    }

    // This is the event handler for the checkbox
    private void c_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        foreach (var control in checkboxcontainer.Children)
        {
            if (control is CheckBox && control != sender)
            {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)control;
                cb.IsChecked = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Has this worked?  Sorry I couldn't provide code in such short space of time.

Comment: Why couldn't you do it, explain what you don't understand?

Comment: Does that make it simpler?

Comment: I've already created one.  The c_Checked function IS an event handler.