# Bind Xaml Radio button to boolean

Tags: wpf, xaml

I saw many posts on how to bind a boolean value to a radio button. But my scenario is that I need to bind it to a radio button and read the selection from the user.

That is no option should be selected intially.

If I bind it to a boolean, since boolean cant be null it shows the default value selected in radio button.

If I use nullable boolean, I still defaults to false when trying to use the converter.

I cant use oneway mode in xaml as I need to check if the radio button selection was made which I do using the bounded variable.

Ant pointers on how to achieve this?

Comment: If it's a boolean why are you wanting to bind to a radio button? Wouldn't a check box be better?

Comment: I considered checkbox but wouldnt it give me the same prob?? selectedvalue is bound to a boolean and using converter will have the same issue??

Comment: No. When the boolean is false the check box is empty. When true it's checked. You can also bind it to a nullable boolean and have that as a third indeterminate state of the check box. What are you trying to achieve here? What does this boolean represent?

Comment: Sorry for that. Im having a yes/no questionnaire where a user needs to answer it either yes or no.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can bind a nullable boolean to your radio buttons, but you need to do it through a converter.

First declare your variable:

```c#
private bool? answer;
public bool? Answer
{
    get { return answer; }
    set
    {
        answer = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Answer"));
    }
}
```

and initialise it to `null`.

Then in the XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BooleanConverter x:Key="BooleanConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
    <RadioButton Content="I Agree"
                 IsChecked="{Binding Answer,
                             Converter={StaticResource BooleanConverter},
                             ConverterParameter='true', Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <RadioButton Content="I Disagree"
                 IsChecked="{Binding Answer,
                             Converter={StaticResource BooleanConverter},
                             ConverterParameter='false', Mode=TwoWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

And finally your converter:

```c#
class BooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var test = (bool?)value;
        var result = bool.Parse((string)parameter);

        if (test == result)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var result = bool.Parse((string)parameter);
        return result;
    }
}
```

This binds the radio button to `Answer` and states that the first one will only be checked when the value is `true` and the second one will be checked when the answer is `false`. You can then check that `Answer` is not null before letting the user proceed.

Comment: Thanks... Im using the exactly same thing, but for some reason before my view is loaded the booleans are getting set to false. I thought it was because of the converter. Ill check whats happening and get back

Comment: @ashishg - Make sure you set the nullable boolean to `null` explicitly in the constructor.

Comment: This works.. the problem was that I was using same variable names as others defined somewhere but available here and every time the view is loaded it was getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way of doing it, but you could use something similar to this:
[checkbox like radiobutton wpf c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320456/checkbox-like-radiobutton-wpf-c-sharp/17320737#17320737)
and just have two controls.

I appreciate it's not the best, but reading your answer it gives you what you want (generally).

Comment: I thought about triggering the event on check/uncheck and do it but yes considered it wouldnt be a great solution and posted it here to see if there is a better way of doing it